# Square of Volume of Tetrahedron in Loop Quantum Gravity

Tags: linear-algebra, volume, loop-quantum-gravity

In the subsequent statement about the geometry of Tetrahedron in Carlo Rovelli's book, there is a formula as follows:

$$V^2 = \frac {2}{9}(\vec L_1 \times \vec L_2)\cdot \vec L_3$$

Where $\vec L_a$ is the $\frac {1}{2}$ of the (outward oriented) vector-product of two edges bounding the triangle.

The volume of tetrahedron is derived from $\frac {1}{6}(det M) $ where $M$ is 3 by 3 matrix.

How to derive the $\frac {2}{9}$ factor?

Comment: The question is one of the problem in Section 7.5.3 of the book. The hint is to consider a tetrahedron that have three sides equal to three orthogonal basis vector s in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: in his paper , a new look at loop quantum gravity, Rovelli writes that 2/9 = (2^3) / (3!^2) gives the volume of a tetrahedron with faces s having areas and normals determined by L_l . it is at the bottom of page 3